# How to center a table from Gutenberg editor

Tags: css, dompdf, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a table with gutenberg.
The HTML file looks like this

```
<figure class="wp-block-table alignright">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="has-text-align-left" data-align="left">text</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="has-text-align-left" data-align="left">text</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <figcaption>my table</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Then I push the HTML to DomPDF to create a PDF, but the table is not "right aligned".

Is it possible to create a CSS style to display the table on the right, while leaving the caption centered ?

i have tried such code, but no luck

```
figure {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.alignright table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-left: auto;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

[image: render]

Thanks

Comment: Is the issue with the caption placement or with the layout in general? Do you have a sample of what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox to align the items, and `flex:1` to adjust the space of the item.

```css
figure {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.alignright figcaption {
  flex:1;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<figure class="wp-block-table alignright">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="has-text-align-left" data-align="left">text</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="has-text-align-left" data-align="left">text</td>
                <td>text</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <figcaption>my table</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Good idea to use flexbox. Unfortunately, DomPDF doesn’t support it.